# Error while running google app scripts to pull data from Google DCM

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, double-click-advertising, google-reporting-trafficking-api

I am trying to use a script to pull some reporting data to google sheets from Google DCM. I did modify the parameters required here and try to run this file. But I get this error `ReferenceError: DoubleClickCampaigns is not defined` What am I doing wrong here.

```
////// UPDATE WITH YOUR DCM REPORT/PROFILE ID & THE GOOGLE SHEETS URL AND TAB NAME ////////////////
                                                                                                  /
var reportId = XXXXXXXXXX;                                                                        /
var profileId = XXXXXXXX;                                                                         /
                                                                                                  /
var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'                                                            /
var TAB_NAME = 'XXXXXXX'                                                                          /
                                                                                                  /
////// DO NOT TOUCH ANYTHING BELOW ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function DCMdownload() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(TAB_NAME);

  var httpOptions = {'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};       
  var additionalParameters = {'synchronous': 'true'};
  var ReportFile = DoubleClickCampaigns.Reports.run(profileId, reportId, additionalParameters);
  var ReportFileID = (ReportFile.id);

  var newReportFile = DoubleClickCampaigns.Files.get(reportId, ReportFileID);
  if(newReportFile.urls) {var httpOptions = {'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};

  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(newReportFile.urls.apiUrl, httpOptions).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
  sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to know the reason of the error message of `ReferenceError: DoubleClickCampaigns is not defined` and remove it.

For this, how about this answer?

I think that the reason of your error message is that "DCM/DFA Reporting And Trafficking API" is not enabled at Advanced Google services. So could you [please confirm whether "DCM/DFA Reporting And Trafficking API" has already been enabled at Advanced Google services?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) And please test it again after it was enabled.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [DCM/DFA Reporting and Trafficking API](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rel_notes)